# SAML Authentication on API Rest, open the authentication page

Tags: rest, api, authentication, single-sign-on, saml

I am really new to SAML, and i had to set up a SAML authentication system.
We are working on API Platform and Angular 7+.

Everything's working fine, the API authenticate to the SSO with SAML and the client authenticate to the API with JWT.

But the problem is, when a user is not authenticated to the SSO, how to tell to the client "redirect the user or open a popup" to the SSO authentication page.

I searched some answers, but it looks like SAML Authentication is not really famous in Rest API World.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if SAML was made to cope with API's. As far as I know it was designed to be used with webpages.

Can't you just return HTTP 401 and leave error handling to the client?
REST service is not supposed to redirect the user to the login page because it is a resource, not a view resolver.

**EDIT:**
As I see it:

1. client sends REST request without Auth header (JWT)
2. API replies with 401 and body like `{"error":"auth required","url":"SSO_http_url"}` without contacting with SSO
3. client has to handle the error - redirect user to SSO service and obtain JWT token
4. client sends new request with valid Auth header (JWT)

Comment: Hi, and thanks for your answer.
The problem is, the API will try to login if there is no Authorization token in the header. So it will send a 301 to the client. But it's not possible to handle 301.

Comment: I think I don't get the problem correctly. API is trying to login into SSO on behalf of the user if he has not presented Authorization token? 301 is returned to API server by the SSO service?

Comment: When we try to authenticates to SAML it redirects us to the SAML Login System (Like the login form), for that it uses 302 (Not 301, sorry). I added an answer with maybe a way to do what i want. Feel free to give your opinion.

Answer (score -1):

I' maybe found a way to do what I want, I must not authenticate the users from the client to SAML with API as a bridge, their will be a lot of problems (Redirections, Cors, etc).

So here are the steps :

- Client tries to authenticate to the API with JWT Token
- Client is not connected, the API returns a 302 to the client for redirecting to the API SAML authentication system.
- The API will try to authenticate the user to SAML (Auto authenticate, redirect to login form, etc)
- When the login success, the API redirects the user to the client with the new JWT Token to allow user access

I hope it'll work ^^